# Why is there a performance drop when using an extracted method?

Tags: c#, methods, refactoring

When writing a small program to compare the performance of a traditional `foreach` with the LINQ `.ToList().ForEach()` on `IEnumerable`, I extracted a small dummy method to be able to quickly change the operations I wanted to test against. That's when I suddenly noticed a drop in my measured times, so this is a small class I created to further test it:

```
class Dummy
{
  public void Iterate()
  {
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(0, 50000000))
    {
      int dummy = n / 2;
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Iterate took {0}ms.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  public void IterateWithMethodCall()
  {
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(0, 50000000))
    {
      SomeOperation(n);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("IterateWithMethodCall took {0}ms.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  private void SomeOperation(int n)
  {
    int dummy = n / 2;
  }
}
```

And this is the entry point:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
  dummy.Iterate();
  dummy.IterateWithMethodCall();
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The output I get on my machine looks like this:

> Iterate took 534ms.
>
> IterateWithMethodCall took 1256ms.

What is the reason behind this? My guess would be that the program has to "jump" to the `SomeOperation` method in every step to execute the code and thus loses time, but I'd love a more rigorous explanation (any reference links on how this exactly works are also welcome).

And does this mean I shouldn't be refactoring more complex operations by extracting pieces of code into smaller methods when every bit of performance is needed?

**Edit:** I looked at the resulting IL code and there is a difference in the loop (release mode); maybe someone could interpret this, I am not able to do so myself. This is only the code of the loop as the rest is identical:

IterateWithMethodCall:

```
    IL_0017: br.s IL_0027
    // loop start (head: IL_0027)
        IL_0019: ldloc.2
        IL_001a: callvirt instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
        IL_001f: stloc.1
        IL_0020: ldarg.0
        IL_0021: ldloc.1
        IL_0022: call instance void WithoutStatic.Dummy::SomeOperation(int32)

        IL_0027: ldloc.2
        IL_0028: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
        IL_002d: brtrue.s IL_0019
    // end loop
```

Iterate:

```
    IL_0017: br.s IL_0024
    // loop start (head: IL_0024)
        IL_0019: ldloc.2
        IL_001a: callvirt instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
        IL_001f: stloc.1
        IL_0020: ldloc.1
        IL_0021: ldc.i4.2
        IL_0022: div
        IL_0023: pop

        IL_0024: ldloc.2
        IL_0025: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
        IL_002a: brtrue.s IL_0019
    // end loop
```

Comment: Is this in release mode or debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in operation time is very easy to explain. Every time a method is called, the CLR-Runtime has to jump to the definition in your compiled CLI code, to execute the method. But this is not the main thing. Moreover the runtime has to to create a new scope on a method call, where every variable and parameter has to be stored. And even if creating and releasing scopes is very very fast, in your range you can recognize the time.

Their is also a difference between debug and release mode. The compiler can recognize if he can embed a simple method, so the code optimization remove your method and replace the code directly in your loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to change to release mode when executing the times (I often forget this...). As soon as I change to release mode, I gain a lot, but it's still roughly 150ms off. Does the compiler still create a new scope even when embedding the code in the loop?

Comment: No, he doesn't, thats one reason why it is faster.

Comment: But shouldn't it be roughly the same execution times in release mode then instead of that difference? Or did I misunderstand you somewhere? That is, why is there still a gap?

Comment: An intresting point would be, looking at the generated CIL code. I take a look later, or you try to post it here.

Comment: I appended the IL code to my original post. I'll accept your answer now though, since my initial question is already answered here :)